# Не получается войти на FTP сервер

Tags: ftp, c++

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь написать FTP-клиент, столкнулся с трудностью. Чтобы зайти на ftp://87.224.183.162/ не требуется ни логина ни пароля. А когда я программно подключаюсь и посылаю команду

```
send(S,"LIST\r\n",strlen("LIST\r\n"),0);
```

сервер отвечает, что я не залогинился. Пытался как-то залогиниться-пустую строку слал. Нет результата. Как быть?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Логиниться на FTP сервере должны все. Вам перед тем как посылать команды LIST нужно послать команды USER и PASS.

Просто все современные (та и не современные) клиенты понимают, что если не задан логин и пароль к фтп то нужно логиниться под юзером "anonymous".

Вот например вывод FileZill'ы

> ```
> Команда:  USER anonymous
> Ответ:    331 User name okay, please send complete E-mail address as password.
> Команда:  PASS **************
> Ответ:    230 User logged in, proceed.
> ```

Comment: А почему работает только небольшой набор команд? Вот, например, не работает: send(S,"SYST\r\n",strlen("SYST\r\n"),0); Как зайти в какой-то каталог? send(S,"CDUP\r\n",strlen("CDUP\r\n"),0); не работает (

Comment: CDUP может не работать потому что нет прав на чтение родительского каталога (CDUP же переходит на уровень выше по каталогам). 

Ну а для того чтобы сменить каталог нужно использовать команду CWD <имя каталога>.

Еще возможно вы неправильно посылаете посылаете команды. Но это уже вам виднее должно быть, я, к сожалению, не знаю C++

Comment: А чтобы получить список каталогов(доступных) нужно отправить LIST? Мне в ответ приходит bin/ls... Но таких каталогов нет...

Comment: Команды `HELP` или `?` что говорят?

Answer (score 2):

Вот лог общения с вашим FTP, получения возможностей и листинга текушего каталога. Обратите внимание, это Serv-U FTP, может надо что про него дополнительно почитать:

```
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Status: Connecting to 87.224.183.162:21...
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Status: Connection established, waiting for welcome message...
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Response: 220 Serv-U FTP Server v12.1 ready...
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Command: USER anonymous
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Response: 331 User name okay, please send complete E-mail address as password.
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Command: PASS **************
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Response: 230 User logged in, proceed.
2013-04-11 22:45:20 8556 9 Command: SYST
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 215 UNIX Type: L8
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Command: FEAT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 211-Extensions supported
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  OPTS MODE;MLST;UTF8
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  CLNT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  CSID Name; Version;
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  HOST domain
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  SITE PSWD;SET;ZONE;CHMOD;MSG;EXEC;HELP
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  AUTH TLS;SSL;TLS-C;TLS-P;
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  PBSZ
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  PROT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  CCC
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  SSCN
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  RMDA directoryname
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  DSIZ
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  AVBL
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  EPRT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  EPSV
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MODE Z
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  THMB BMP|JPEG|GIF|TIFF|PNG max_width max_height pathname
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  REST STREAM
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  SIZE
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MDTM
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MDTM YYYYMMDDHHMMSS[+-TZ];filename
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MFMT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MFCT
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MFF Create;Modify;
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  XCRC filename;start;end
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  XMD5 filename;start;end
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  XSHA1 filename;start;end
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  XSHA256 filename;start;end
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  XSHA512 filename;start;end
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  COMB target;source_list
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response:  MLST Type*;Size*;Create;Modify*;Perm;Win32.ea;Win32.dt;Win32.dl
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 211 End (for details use "HELP commmand" where command is the command of interest)
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Status: Server does not support non-ASCII characters.
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Command: OPTS MLST type;size;modify;perm;
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 200 MLST OPTS Type;Size;Modify;Perm;
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Status: Connected
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Status: Retrieving directory listing...
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Command: PWD
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 257 "/" is current directory.
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Command: TYPE I
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 200 Type set to I.
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Command: PASV
2013-04-11 22:45:21 8556 9 Response: 227 Entering Passive Mode (87,224,183,162,200,156)
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Command: MLSD
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD.
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Response: 226 Transfer complete. 2 099 bytes transferred. 2,05 KB/sec.
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Status: Directory listing successful
2013-04-11 22:55:23 8556 9 Response: 421 Connection timed out - closing.
```

Comment: А где именно выведен список каталогов? В логе его нет... 
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Command: MLSD
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Response: 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for MLSD.
2013-04-11 22:45:22 8556 9 Response: 226 Transfer complete. 2 099 bytes transferred.

Comment: Это лог клиента, а не вывод консоли :) Под Win у меня та же фигня, а под линуксом:

    klopp:~ $ftp 87.224.183.162
    Connected to 87.224.183.162.
    220 Serv-U FTP Server v12.1 ready...
    Name (87.224.183.162:klopp): anonymous
    331 User name okay, please send complete E-mail address as password.
    Password:
    230 User logged in, proceed.
    Remote system type is UNIX.
    Using binary mode to transfer files.
    ftp> ls
    200 PORT command successful.
    150 Opening ASCII mode data connection for /bin/ls.
    drwxrwxrwx   1 user     group           0 Apr 11 18:03 ! ! 2013
...

Comment: Всю сеть облазил, совершенно не ясно как получить список каталогов на FTP...

Comment: Наберите в вашем ftp команду `HELP`. Он поддерживает как минимум `ls` и `dir`. В теории. Но почему-то только если заходить из линукса (см. выше, `ls` работает). Но если заходить родным ftp-клиентом из-под Windows, то точно так же виснет на ожидании /bin/ls. С другой стороны, виндовая же FileZilla получает листинг без проблем. Значит, копать надо где-то в этой стороне, смотреть в чём отличия в linux, filezilla и виндовом ftp.

Comment: Я так понял, что список каталогов, файлов, отправляется в виде файла... это так?

Comment: Список каталогов отправляется точно так же, как и результат любой другой команды - грубо говоря, в виде набора байт, посылаемых от сервера клиенту.